# How to change the Button string in a partial form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these html's

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1> New Customer </h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Edit customer</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

And then

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model: @customer, local: true do |form| %>
  ...

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', customers_path %>
```

So now The Button generated by form.submit just has a generic text.

Its either    `Update Customer` or `Create Customer`.

How can I change it to custom text?!

Thank you

Comment: You can find some more information in the Rails API https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a string along as a parameter.

```
<%= form.submit "Save changes" %>
```

Comment: You just got in ahead of me.

Comment: Ha I know how that goes. I upvoted one of your past accepted answers as an olive branch!

Comment: hey you were faster and allthough the other had the answer I really looked after (changing it depending weither it is editing or updating). I will give you the right answer tick

Comment: @MrDanA Thanks, that's kind of you. I really wasn't angry about it, just more of a doh.jpg moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your desired string inside the erb tag.

`<%= form.submit 'Your text' %>`

or if you want to change the text based on if the object is being created vs being edited:

`<%= f.submit foo.persisted? ? 'Update Foo' : 'Create Foo' %>`

Comment: thank you this is exactly what I wanted (the second part). I feel bad that someone answered before you without this information but in general answering the question right. I would give you the answer if I hadnt messed up my question sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can change the default values in `config/locales/en.yml`. (If the file doesn't exist you'll have to create it.) This custom locales file overrides the defaults of Rails itself.

```
en:
  helpers:
    select:
      # Default value for :prompt => true in FormOptionsHelper
      prompt: "Please select"

    # Default translation keys for submit and button FormHelper
    submit:
      create: 'Create %{model}'
      update: 'Update %{model}'
      submit: 'Save %{model}'
```

See: [*ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder#submit*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-submit) and [action_view/locale/en.yml](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/834be61e61a1ed55f056cdff12ffe4cdcaa7ca65/actionview/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml#L47-L56)

You can find more info about the locale files in the [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Comment: thats really nice to know for a beginner like me, thank you